# Synchronizing worker with UI thread

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading

Working on an existing project, I've got to use WinForms (haven't worked with it for a while) and have got an issue synchronizing with the UI thread.

The design I've got to integrate with works as follows: A `BackgroundWorker` gets an `Action` as a parameter and executes it asynchronously. The action I'm working on has two parts; a core class (containing the business logic) and a GUI part being notified by the core through events if it has to request user interaction.

I've added the handle creation to the constructor of the form

```
if (!IsHandleCreated)
{
    //be sure to create the handle in the constructor
    //to allow synchronization with th GUI thread
    //when using Show() or ShowDialog()
    CreateHandle();
}
```

With this, following code works:

```
private DialogResult ShowDialog(Form form)
{
    DialogResult dialogResult = DialogResult.None;
    Action action = delegate { dialogResult = form.ShowDialog(); };
    form.Invoke(action);
    return dialogResult;
}
```

For this example, the startup location has been set to windows default.

If I change it to:

```
Action action = delegate { dialogResult = form.ShowDialog(ParentWindow); };
```

Where `ParentWindow` is an instance of `IWin32Window` and the `WindowStartupLocation` is set to `CenterParent`. I get a cross-thread exception when calling `form.Invoke(action)`.

> Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'ActivationConfirmationForm' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.

**Questions:**

- Why is there a cross thread exception only when setting the startup location as `CenterParent`? And how do I avoid it?
- Why is `form.InvokeRequired` always `false`?

Both are probably related!?

[edit]
@Reniuz:
You're not missing anything here ;)
The call is being made from a listener being notified by the core

```
private static void OnActivationConfirmationRequired(DmsPackageConfiguratorCore sender,
ConfigurationActivationConfirmationEventArgs args)
{
    args.DoAbort = (ShowDialog(new ActivationConfirmationForm(args.Data)) == DialogResult.No);
}
```

Everything at my disposal is in the GUI interface

```
/// <summary>
/// Interface defining methods and properties used to show dialogs while performing package specific operations
/// </summary>
public interface IPackageConfiguratorGui
{
/// <summary>
/// Gets or sets the package configurator core.
/// </summary>
/// <value>The package configurator core.</value>
IPackageConfiguratorCore PackageConfiguratorCore { get; set; }

/// <summary>
/// Gets or sets the parent window.
/// </summary>
/// <value>The parent window.</value>
IWin32Window ParentWindow { get; set; }

/// <summary>
/// Gets the package identifier.
/// </summary>
/// <value>The package identifier.</value>
PackageIdentifier PackageIdentifier { get; }
}
```

Comment: is the cross-thread exception firing because of the `CenterParent` or because you are actually setting the parent window (i.e. does it still fire if you remove the `CenterParent` setting)?

Comment: @Strillo it does always fire when setting the ParentWindow

Comment: form invokes to show itself? Or Iam missing something here? Can you post all code?

Comment: @Reniuz I've added the answer in the post itself (for formatting reasons...)

Comment: I think the problem might be that you are trying to access a window (ParentWindow) for which you don't have a handle.
What if you try to expose the `CreateHandle` method for the parent window and then call it in your child code either in the constructor or before executing your action?

Comment: @Strillo unfortunately I can't expose such a function and remain generic. I'll use it without the ParentWindow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seeing form.InvokeRequired at *false* is the core of your problem.  You know it has to be true.  The simple explanation is that the form object that is passed to your ShowDialog() method is the wrong object.  Classic mistake is to use *new* to create the instance instead of using the existing instance of the form object, the one that the user is looking at and was created on the main thread.  Be sure that the threaded code has a reference to that form object so it can pass the correct reference.  Only use Application.OpenForms[0] if you can't get it right.

In general, decouple the threaded code from the user interface.  A worker thread has no business displaying a dialog.  You can make it work but it doesn't work well in practice.  The dialog pops up without the user expecting it.  Making accidents likely, the user might click or press a key a fraction of a second before the dialog pops up.  Dismissing the dialog without even seeing it.  The CreateHandle() hack similarly should *not* be in your code.  Just don't start the thread until the user interface is ready.  Signaled by the form's Load event.

Comment: Thanks for explaining! The form is actually created on the fly in the GUI part of of the worker and not by the GUI thread. This is a design issue I can't change. Users will have to live with the dialogues popping up at the windows default location ;)

Answer (score 1):

ok I have no permission to "comment" since i'm a new user, so i'll just use this answer space.

you are creating a new instance of a form ActivationConfirmationForm, whichever thread you are in, the creation of this form and the execution of ShowDialog is executing in the same thread context, since this is true, the InvokeRequired (see msdn) is obviously going to be false since the form that you want to access is created in the thread in which you are accessing it. No need to use invoke/begininvoke etc. Kind of what @reniuz was worried about.

Answer (score 1):

The form belongs to a different thread to the parent.

It appears that WinForms CenterParent position argument makes a call to the WinForms .Net object rather than using the Win32 API to find the parent window position from the HWND, and this cross-thread call is what causes the cross thread exception.

The real answer is worker threads shouldn't have UI. They should give a result which indicates that user intervention is required and the main thread should take care of user interaction.

Failing that, don't set a parent window for the worker thread GUI. It might (just) be workable if you have only one worker thread, but it will cause all sorts of confusion if you have more than none.

If you absolutely must, use P/Invoke to find the current window position of the parent window from the Win32API and set it explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

As a follow up:
I've now got a working solution (the dialogue wasn't modal without setting the parent). I'll agree it's not the nicest thing to launch a dialogue from a worker thread, but in this case it is a requirement. ParentForm is now a Form, as opposed to a IWin32Window before

Create the dialogue in the graphical thread:

```
private void OnActivationConfirmationRequired(DmsPackageConfiguratorCore sender, ConfigurationActivationConfirmationEventArgs args)
{
    //create the dialog in the graphical thread
    ActivationConfirmationForm dialog = null;
    Action createDialogInGuiThread = () => dialog = new ActivationConfirmationForm(args.Data);
    ParentForm.Invoke(createDialogInGuiThread);

    if (dialog != null)
    {
        args.DoAbort = (ShowDialog(dialog) == DialogResult.No);
    }
}
```

Invoke the dialogue from the UI thread

```
private DialogResult ShowDialog(Form form)
{
    DialogResult dialogResult = DialogResult.None;

    //launch the form in the graphical htread (the one of the parent form)
    Action action = delegate { dialogResult = form.ShowDialog(ParentForm); };
    ParentForm.Invoke(action);

    return dialogResult;
}
```

As all the graphical stuff is being done in the UI thread, the handle creation isn't required anymore.